# Filter multiple values in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

My filter function here works great, however it only filters the first name (see code). So I was wondering what the "best" way to make it filter by surname and phone too (see image)!
Here's my filter at the moment:

```
const filteredUsers = this.state.dataToDisplay.filter(item => {
  return (
    /*Only firstname!*/item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) >= 0
  )
})
```

And here's the image:
[image]

Thanks a lot! :D

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are using filtering on the Javascript array level so just extend your criteria:

```
const filteredUsers = this.state.dataToDisplay.filter(item => {
  const query = this.state.search.toLowerCase();

  return (
    item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) >= 0 ||
    item.surname.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) >= 0 || 
    item.phone.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) >= 0
  )
});
```

Comment: Doesn't that go agains the DRY principle? Thanks for answering tho! :D

Comment: You can create a function where you will normalize to lower case and then call it for each attribute you have - that's code optimization :). Something like `ignoreCaseCompare(value1, value2)`

Answer (score 3):

Just add more conditions to filter function

```
    const filteredUsers = this.state.dataToDisplay.filter(item => {
          return (
              item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) >= 0 
              || item.surname.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) >= 0 
              || item.phone.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
          )
        })
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this code, eg:

```js
const filterField = (search, value) => value.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) >= 0;

const orFilter = (search, values) => values.some(filterField.bind(null, search));

const filteredUsers = this.state.dataToDisplay.filter(item =>
  orFilter(this.state.search, [item.name, item.surname, phone]);
)
```